# Populate value A with value from variable B in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

```
   @RequestMapping("/new") 
        public String addNewClient(Model model) {
            
            UserForAdmin userForAdmin = new UserForAdmin();
            
            model.addAttribute("userForAdmin", userForAdmin);
            
            return "new";



    @PostMapping("/save")
        public String saveClient(@ModelAttribute("userForAdmin") UserForAdmin userForAdmin) {
            
             userForAdminService.save(userForAdmin);
             
             return "redirect:/";   
        }
      






new.html
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${userForAdmin}"
            method="post">
 
            <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{phone}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Package:</td>
                    <td> <select th:field="*{packages}">
                        <option th:value="'10'" th:text="10"></option>
                        <option th:value="'5'" th:text="5"></option>
                        <option th:value="'3'" th:text="3"></option>
                    </select> </td>
         
                <tr>
                    <td>Session left:</td>
                    <td th:field="*{sessionleft}" th:value="*{packages}">  </td>
                </tr>
```

I am adding new User, I have dropdown list with packages: 10, 5 or 3. Everything is good, on my index page I retrieve what I've chosen. But I want to set also value from dropdown list on my amount of sessions. So e.g. **When choose PACKAGE 10 and I want to automatically set SESSION LEFT 10**. So I chose in one place and I populate two value in database. I have tried with th:value="*{packages}" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear about what you are asking but if you are asking to pre populate the form then I can help you. You can use inline javascript to repopulate the form. Here is how:

```
               <select id="value" onClick="change()" th:field="*{packages}">
                      <option th:value="10" th:text="10"></option>
                      <option th:value="5" th:text="5"></option>
                      <option th:value="3" th:text="3"></option>
               </select> 

                 <tr >
                    <td >Session left:</td>
                    <input id="session" type='text' >//I have used input for testing purpose only, you can change accordingly
                </tr>

              <script th:inline="javascript">
                function change(){
                    let value=document.getElementById("value").value;
                    console.log(value);
                    document.getElementById('session').value=value;
                }
            
             </script>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I need to do this without js. So I will try to explain my question better. I have index.html where I have my list with new Users. And when I am on new.html I want to create a new User (and everything is here ok). But when I choose package for this User (e.g. package '10') I want to get automatically value of this package in my column: session left. So thanks to my choice in package dropdown list I want to get same value in package column and session left column. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Ok, so you want to get the value in your packages column of you database using userForAdmin entity right?. And are you getting the value in sessionleft field?.

Comment: No no, I want to get the same value in my packages column AND sessionleft column thanks to my choice in dropdown list. For example I clicked on value='10' and I want to create my new User with my selected package and automatically set sessionleft. (for now I retrieve my selected package correctly, but sessionleft are NULL)

Comment: ok i got it. But to help you I might need your whole project but before that try adding th:field="*{sessionleft}" in all your option tags like this :                                                                      <option th:field="*{sessionleft}" th:value="'10'" th:text="10"></option>
                        <option th:field="*{sessionleft}" th:value="'5'" th:text="5"></option>
                        <option th:field="*{sessionleft}" th:value="'3'" th:text="3"></option>            Let me know if this works.

Comment: It was great idea but I got this error :( "If specified (which is not required), attribute "{th:field,data-th-field}" in "option" tag must have exactly the same value as in its containing "select" tag"

Comment: Well, worth a shot. But i am not out of ideas yet. Try like this for every option                                <option name="value" th:value="10" th:text="10"> <input type="hidden" th:field="*{sessionleft}" th:value="10"></option>
                            <option name="value" th:value="5" th:text="5"><input type="hidden" th:field="*{sessionleft}" th:value="10"></option>
                            <option name="value" th:value="3" th:text="3"><input type="hidden" th:field="*{sessionleft}" th:value="10"></option>

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work and I got a warning "invalid location of tag input"

Comment: I got it! So I just had to create userForAdmin.setSessionleft(userForAdmin.getPackages()); in saveClient method. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Great, so can you give me a tick bro?. I need it to show it to my teacher.:D